# Test Class for recursive trigger class

Tags: unit-test, recursion

I have the following class which I put into a Contact trigger and in sandbox it gets 100% coverage.  However, I can't deploy to prod with the Contact Test class. (0% code coverage) I wrote a test class for it but I get an error.
Trigger:

```
@isTest  
public class RecursiveTests {

    @isTest
    static void testRecursive() {

        system.assert(CheckRecursive.runOnce());

        system.assert(!CheckRecursive.runOnce());
        system.assert(!CheckRecursive.runOnce());
        system.assert(!CheckRecursive.runOnce());
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you should be using `CheckRecursive.runOnce` instead of `cr.runOnce`.

```
system.assert(CheckRecursive.runOnce());
system.assert(!CheckRecursive.runOnce());
```

Comment: Thanks, sfdcfox!  I'm now getting the following error: Compile Error: Illegal variable declaration: system.assert at line 8 column 9   I have updated the code in my original question.

Comment: I didn't realize he answered this one. Why did you add that first line in your test? Of course it won't compile. Just remove that line entirely.

Comment: Now I can't see his comment, sorry.  Ok, I think I've redone this so many times, I'm confused.  I have updated my code again.

Comment: I'm telling you, remove that first line that contains only `CheckRecursive.runOnce`. It's nonsense.

Comment: Got it, I pasted that junk in, thank you so much @Adrian Larson!  No I have 0 test methods and my once 100% class shows 0%.  Ugh.

Comment: Did you accidentally remove `@IsTest`? Fwiw I prefer `testMethod` instead.

Comment: I don't think so and traditionally, I do too but this code was some that I found that didn't work so I manipulated it.  This is what the code looks like today & now I'm getting a 'Variable does not exist' when I try to deploy the test class to prod.  '@isTest'
    public class RecursiveTests {
    '@isTest'
    static void testRecursive() {
             system.assert(CheckRecursive.runOnce());
    
            system.assert(!CheckRecursive.runOnce());
            system.assert(!CheckRecursive.runOnce());
            system.assert(!CheckRecursive.runOnce());
        }
    }

Comment: this is what I'm getting now: Variable does not exist: CheckRecursive